# Are browser tabs child windows?

Tags: winapi, browser, scroll

I've been recently dabbling with writing applications in win32 (i run win10). Windows has this concept of parent windows and child windows each of which can be customized to do various things.

What does this structure like in a browser like chrome/firefox? I read somewhere that browsers don't have a concept of "windows" in the win32 sense. However, Spy++ shows that each tab of a browser window has a unique window handle (likely for interfacing with windows). But the "tab handle" does not have any other children.

If we consider a webpage that is broken into multiple sections, each with its own scrollbar, how does the browser know which scrollbar is active? I imagine that the browser would likely use the mouse pointer location to figure this out once a scroll message (in the win32 sense) is sent to it.

Fundamentally, what kind of code structure do browsers use?

A related, albeit distant question- how is the scroll without focus functionality implemented in windows? I believe the answer to this leads from the first but if its not, I'll make this a separate question.

Thanks!

PS. I only know C++.

PPS. Links to resources that can get me started are just as important and much appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Browsers generally go with *"windowless controls"*. Ultimately, there's just a single top-level window, and the application custom-renders everything else. It's not just rendering, though, it's also input handling. Not recommended. To be honest, I'm still confused, why browser don't re-use control behavior, and only only do custom rendering.

Comment: I suspect the main reason chrome and firefox go the single-window route is that it was easier to achieve platform independence that way, either that or it was easier on the platform of original implementation. On the other hand I am pretty sure that IE did use multiple windows.

Comment: @IInspectable I lost you there. Are you saying that the custom input handling is not recommended? ^^  Also, could you elaborate on what you mean by reusing control behaviour?

Comment: @SoronelHaetir I can see the platform independence part. It would make sense that you want to reuse as much code as possible between multiple platforms and a single window could help there. Just curious about this... Does linux and macOS use a similar windowing concept?

Comment: Custom-drawn controls have full control over their visuals yet inherit the entire control behavior. Including input handling and state management. That may appear to be straight forward until you consider a global user base.

Comment: Windowless controls are usually accessed via _IAccessible_.

Comment: Doesn't Chrome spawn an actual child process for each pane? I don't see how that could even work with normal child windows and playing nice with the Win32 API.

Comment: Sounds possible given the large number of chrome processes I see in task manager. Since I'm on windows, I had this naive hope that i could send a scroll message to other windows from my application. 

This worked on acrobat reader, notepad and notepad++ but failed stupendously on browsers. Spy++ shows that my commands go to the correct window but nothing happens there haha!

Now, I know that browsers use a ton of windowless controls so affecting it has to be done differently. Something through the Windows UI Automation API/ IAccessible as Alex pointed out above.

Comment: If the browser has only one scroll bar, you can directly send a message to [achieve scrolling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eHipW.gif). If you need to individually control multiple scroll bars in a webpage, then what you said `IAccessible` will work.